# Selenium on Mac Using Python, how to issue keyboard commands

Tags: python, macos, selenium, command

I've been trying to issue keyboard commands using selenium in python in brave browser.
I've tried things like:
`body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")`

`body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND,"t")`
Which seems to run fine, but produces no effect. What am I doing wrong? It seems like I'm executing the command to the wrong place, but if so, where do I send it do?

Comment: I was expecting it to open a new tab

Comment: Syntax seems to be : send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "t")

Comment: I found a workaround, thanks.

Comment: Can you post as an answer ?

Comment: Yes, just posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I basically did:

`````
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
        import time 
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
  
options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser'
driver_path = '/Users/[myusername]/Desktop/seleni/chromedriver'

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, executable_path = driver_path)
browser.get('chrome://newtab') #or whatever page you want

#Here's the important part vvv
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27&t=brave&ia=answer')")````

Hopefully this helps in some way. Sorry if I'm a bit of a newbie at this kind of stuff.
`````